# PyQT and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, pyqt, ptvs

I'm using PyQT v4.9 for Windows 7, and Visual Studio 2010 (extension PTVS 1.1 )
Autocomplete is good function in IDE. Example:
   object.method_of_class() #when I press the dot, see a list of possible methods.

But with pyqt class, this not works, exapmle:
    QtGui.QDesktopWidget()

How can I solve this problem?

P.S. Forgive me for my bad English

Comment: Don't know about VS2010, but [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) supports autocomplete for `PyQt`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with PTVS version 1.1.1 . I did the following . Now auto completion works for PyQT libraries.
1. upgraded the  PTVS to 1.5
2. In visual studio , select tools-options- python tools-interpreter options. Click on "Generate completion" , then restart  the visual studio.